# lxml - ignore <br> tag in html

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml

I wrote a tiny html-parser in Python using lxml. It's very useful, but I have a problem.

I have the following code:

```
tags = doc.xpath('//table//tr/td[@align="right"]/b')
for tag in tags:
    print(x.text.strip())
```

It works fine. But if there is a `<br>` tag inside a `<b>` element, like this:

```
<b> first-half <br>
    second-half </b>
```

this code will only print `first-half` into the `<b>` tag.

How can I get all of text in `<b>` even if there is a `<br>` tag?

Thanks.

Comment: That's ill-formed HTML. Have you tried getting the text of the child tag of that tag?

Comment: Are you parsing this as XML or as HTML?

Comment: Try `x.text_content()`. It should be able to filter out the break.

Comment: @shau-kote, I'm having the same problem. I was able to solve it with `text_content()` but now it joins the strings. So in your example it would result `first-halfsecond-half`. How did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `text_content()` to extract all of the non-markup text within a tag. Replace `x.text` with `x.text_content()`.